# SOAP java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time

Tags: php, api, soap

I'm getting this error when I try to connect to the soap-server and use a method.

```
[previous:Exception:private] => 
[faultstring] => java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time
[faultcode] => soapenv:Server.userException
[detail] => stdClass Object
 (
  [hostname] => bast.itek.handelsbanken.se
)
```

Any idea ?

And how can I see what my soap-request looks like?

Here is my code snippet:

http://pastebin.com/apTw5Zhh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some more details would be nice. How do you connect to the server? You labeled the question as php, yet show a Java exception, I guess it's from the server? You could try to put a proxy between your client and the server to monitor your requests.

Without seeing anything I would guess that some date field is in another format than the server expects. Try to log your requests and compare them to sample requests (if you can find any) and to the WSDL/XSD describing the service.

Edit: I would guess, this line is giving you problems:

```
 $score->request->contract->params->deliveryDate = '2013-02-11'
```

Try without that line or try adding a time to the date, although it should be ok for a XML date.

And maybe try playing around with the server, figuring out the correct requests with a tool like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) until you know what exactly you want.

Comment: Oh I would love to help out with more information, but I can I best do this ?:

Comment: Alright, so I accepted your answer hence that removed the problem. But I cannot get this to work, now it's getting me answer:     [faultstring] => org.xml.sax.SAXException: operation description is missing parameter description!
    [faultcode] => soapenv:Server.userException

Comment: give SoapUI a try and fiddle around with the request there until it works, then transplant it into your code. soapUI can also generate a valid request for you and/or validate your xml against the wsdl.

Comment: Alright, I downloaded the program, got a nice XML generated file. Which I downloaded, filled in the information needed.

But I cannot load it with simplexml_load_file, do you have any idea for that? :)

Comment: you can use the program to fire your request against the server straight away. If you're talking about a php function, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: had to downgrade the PHP to 7.2 top make it work. so annoying